# Logistic Curve displaying a straight line

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic

I tried plotting the logistic curve in R using ggplot2 but am getting a straight line instead of the s-shaped curve. The image I received is displayed below

[image]

below is my code

```
`log_mydata <- glm(Results ~ Age, data=mydata, family=binomial)
```

`ggplot(log_mydata, aes(x=Age, y=Results)) + 
              geom_point() +
              stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), se=FALSE`)

[[image: My glm output]]

Comment: @Roland, see `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=qsec, y=vs))` instead.

Comment: I wonder if this is due to your predictor having no discrimination, and also low prevalence

Comment: We can't tell from this plot, but if you have may more observations with results == 0, this will happen. The estimate is always low. I don't think the line is straight, it's just not very variable.

Comment: Perhaps you can include your data in the question, or the outcome of `glm`.

Comment: I have included the outcome of the glm but don't know how to upload the data

Comment: My data has 16930 observations with the categorical variable having 0==  16502 and 1==428

Comment: Ok, so nothing wrong then. The regression line shows that for all Ages, Result is very unlikely to be 1, and slightly more unlikely for higher ages. The line just seems linear because of the scale.

Comment: Unbalanced data like this will always yield a model that favors no discrimination. This model could predict 0 for everyone and still be about 98% accurate.